# Vue: how to apply multiple global mixins

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am currently working on a Vue project including multiple applications. 
It has project-wide used methods and application-wide used methods.
Therefore, I created 2 mixins which need to be available in every Vue component. However, I don't know how to implement it using Vue.mixin().
Please help.

I tried this. Not work..

The error says `"Cannot read property 'VALIDATION' of undefined"`.
Somehow URL is not imported. URL() returns a object where urls are defined according to either DEV or PRODUCTION mode.

```
import global_mixin from './global_mixin.js'
import application_mixin from './application_mixin.js'

Vue.mixin(global_mixin)
Vue.mixin(application_mixin)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

global_mixin.js

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // data items
    }
  }
}
```

application_mixin.js

```
import { URL } from './_util'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      URL_VALIDATION: URL().VALIDATION
    }
  }
}
```

_util.js

```
import store from './_store'

export const URL = () => {
  const urls = {
    PROD: {
      VALIDATION: '/api/web/company/profile/validation',
      PROFILE: '/api/web/company/profile',
      COUNTRY: '/api/app/countries',
      ADDRESS: '/api/web/address'
    },
    DEV: {
      PROFILE: '/data/profile_company.json',
      VALIDATION: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
      COUNTRY: '/data/countries.json',
      ADDRESS: '/data/zip.json'
    }
  }

  return urls[store.getters.mode]
}
```

Comment: Can you show us these `mixin` implementations?

Comment: Try to put inside `new Vue({` this `mixins: [global_mixin, application_mixin]`

Comment: What are global_mixin and application_mixin and what does 'Not work' mean? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: @YomS. Added mixin codes.

Comment: @estus Added codes and actual error I'm getting.

Comment: @EmīlsGulbis Tried your suggestion, but the result was same.

Comment: @YosukeSato Please make sure the `store.getters.mode` resolves to either `PROD` or `DEV`; otherwise, that's just gonna give you `undefined` as a result. I think you should put a breakpoint and debug that part.

Comment: @YomS. Ah, you are right. Vuex getter doesn't return anything there.. If I set a static value "DEV", it works. But why? Vuex store is not set when the script runs???

Comment: @YosukeSato Maybe at that point the Vue instance isn't already installed or mounted?